# Kanban / Scrum software

Tags: scrum, kanban

My team currently uses zenhub, and are looking for something to better fit our needs

Current Needs ( Most are met by zenhub )

- Must be able to paste image from clipboard into ticket ( having to upload an image is unacceptable )
- Muliple swimplanes ( Main reason I want to get away from zenhub )
- A Customer Portal that they can submit tickets and view the status of there tickets, or tickets tied to there customer ( or some other way to limit so one customer can not view another one's tickets )

Would be nice to have, but not a deal breaker

- Github intigration ( close tickets, move column ext, from git commit )
- an api we can hook into

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic most places on SE except for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. If you can rewrite your question as a process problem with a canonical answer, you may avoid closure or enable the community to re-open your question.

Comment: That is a bad policy.  We live in a world where we rely on software to do our jobs, not just canonical answers, and this is the project management forum.  We shouldn't have to go to a completely separate exchange site to get recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what kind of budget do you have?  I am not aware of any free solutions that have all the features you like.  However, I can tell you I have used a couple of free solutions in my job which are quite good and worth a look:

kanbanflow.com (my fave chanson solution)
Pivotal Tracker (awesome mobile app to go with it)

If you have a budget, the best expensive solution I have found is Jira.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I agree that Jira is the best solution, And we have the budget for it, One of my co-workers absolutly hates jira though so It might be a hard sell ( He hates the ui look and feel, not any functionality )

Comment: The cure for that is to make him use TFS for a couple months.  Then he will hunger for JIRA.